# RShiny: Writing reactive functions to reduce code repetition

Tags: r, shiny, dry

I have a shiny application that is composed of many pieces which are all the same, except that they work on different slices of a dataset. Here's a toy example that manipulates and displays two subsets of an initial dataset independently:

```
# app.R
library(shinydashboard)

df <- data.frame(
  id    = 1:10,
  group = rep(c("A", "B"), times = 5),
  val   = seq(1, 100, 10)
)


ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    numericInput(
      "A_multiplier",
      "Multiplier:",
      value = 1
    ),
    tableOutput("A_table")
  ),
  fluidRow(
    numericInput(
      "B_multiplier",
      "Multiplier:",
      value = 1
    ),
    tableOutput("B_table")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  A_data <- reactive({
    df <- df[df$group == "A", ]
    df$val <- df$val * input$A_multiplier
    df
  })

  output$A_table <- renderTable(A_data())

  B_data <- reactive({
    df <- df[df$group == "B", ]
    df$val <- df$val * input$B_multiplier
    df
  })

  output$B_table <- renderTable(B_data())
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

That's a ton of code repetition, and becomes very hard to maintain as the number of groups increases.

What I want to do is write functions to generate the `ui` and `server` code based on the groups seen in the initial `df`, treating each group the same way.

For the `ui` this is pretty straightforward; I can replace the `ui` block with the following:

```
MakeGroupElements <- function(group) {

  namer <- function(name) paste(group, name, sep = "_")

  fluidRow(
    numericInput(
      namer("multiplier"),
      "Multiplier:",
      value = 1
    ),
    tableOutput(namer("table"))
  )
}

ui <- do.call(fluidPage, lapply(unique(df$group), MakeGroupElements))
```

to produces the same application as before in a more maintainable fashion.

What I can't figure out is how to similarly refactor the server side. It would be easy if I didn't have the inputs, but I'm having a hard time properly handling the reactivity.

How can I refactor the `server` block to prevent code repetition?

---

**Clarification:**

I failed to mention originally that I separated the data generation from the `renderTable` calls because in my real application, I have *multiple* outputs (tables, charts, buttons, etc.) which reactively depend on the group-subsetted data, so an ideal solution will allow for such extension.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi I already have the UI figured out; no need to render it server-side. I want to code the `server` side in a flexible, maintainable way similar to how I refactored the `ui` side above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lapply` in your `server.R` as well:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
        lapply(unique(df$group),function(x){
                output[[paste0(x,"_table")]] <- renderTable({
                        df <- df[df$group == x, ]    
                        df$val <- df$val * input[[paste0(x,"_multiplier")]]
                        df
                })
        })
}
```

`input` and `output` are lists so you can set/access elements using `[[`

You can use `reactiveValues` if you want to keep the data in a list:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- reactiveValues()

  lapply(
    unique(df$group),
    function(x) {
      data[[as.character(x)]] <- reactive({
        df <- df[df$group == x, ]
        df$val <- df$val * input[[paste(x, "multiplier", sep = "_")]]
        df
      })
    }
  )

  lapply(
    unique(df$group),
    function(x) {
      output[[paste(x, "table", sep = "_")]] <- renderTable({data[[as.character(x)]]()})
    }
  )
}
```

---

**Additional Outputs and Refactoring:**

We can add another output (a plot), and refactor further to break things out into small functions like this:

```
# app.R
library(shinydashboard)

df <- data.frame(
  id    = 1:10,
  group = rep(c("A", "B"), times = 5),
  val   = seq(1, 100, 10)
)


MakeNamer <- function(group) {
  function(name) {paste(group, name, sep = "_")}
}


MakeGroupElements <- function(group) {

  namer <- MakeNamer(group)

  fluidRow(
    numericInput(
      namer("multiplier"),
      "Multiplier:",
      value = 1
    ),
    tableOutput(namer("table")),
    plotOutput(namer("plot"))
  )
}


ui <- do.call(fluidPage, lapply(unique(df$group), MakeGroupElements))


MakeReactiveData <- function(df, input) {

  data <- reactiveValues()

  lapply(
    unique(df$group),
    function(group) {
      data[[as.character(group)]] <- reactive({
        namer <- MakeNamer(group)
        df <- df[df$group == group, ]
        df$val <- df$val * input[[namer("multiplier")]]
        df
      })
    }
  )

  data
}


MakeOutputs <- function(groups, data, output) {

  lapply(
    groups,
    function(group) {
      namer <- MakeNamer(group)
      df <- reactive({data[[as.character(group)]]()})
      output[[namer("table")]] <- renderTable({df()})
      output[[namer("plot")]] <- renderPlot({plot(df()$id, df()$val)})
    }
  )
}


server <- function(input, output) {

  data <- MakeReactiveData(df, input)

  MakeOutputs(unique(df$group), data, output)
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

While overkill for this toy example, in a larger application with more groups and outputs this reduction in code repetition leads to a much more maintainable application.

Some important things to notice are using `as.character` when indexing into `data` and the need to wrap `df` with another `reactive`  inside `MakeOutputs()` so it can be more easily referenced more than once when building outputs.

Comment: What if I have multiple outputs which draw from the reactive dataset, which would prevent me from putting the data generation inside the `renderTable` call? Sorry I didn't specify that in the question; editing now. Also, will issues arise if I break that anonymous function out to a named function contained in a separate file?